# iphone object c is object already released

Tags: iphone, memory-management

i release an image with                 [myimageview.image release];

but after the app was in background it comes foreground again it release that image again, so it crash! All my tries to check if the app came from a background did not worked.
So how could i check if an object is already released.. so i dont do it twice?

thankx
chris

EDIT
After several complains about my bad coding :) here an example:

First I initialize an Array with the path to a lot of fullscreen images
Also there are around 10 Different Arrays for 10 different Scenes.
When I put directly the Images in an array it just needed to much memory from the beginning, or when i released a scene totaly , it needed to load the whole image array again and that came to slow. So I just load the path to the images into an array and assign each pic in a loop to my imageview while runtime.

Init once:
       imageArray_stand= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       @"FrankieArmeRaus_0001.jpg",
                                            ... up to 60 Images
                       @"FrankieArmeRaus_0061.jpg",nil];

In a Loop thats called each 1/10 Second:

```
      if ([myimageview.image  retainCount] > 1) 
        //if ( myimageview.image != nil) // does not work = crash
        {   
             [myimageview.image release]; 
              myimageview.image = nil;
        }

        myimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray_stand2 objectAtIndex:piccounter-1]];
```

Problem came, because when the app went into background and than into foreground again it seems to release the image 2 times, so i needed a solution to check that.

I am happy about any solution (just NOW it works) thats better.
Even to load all images completly into an array, but as mentioned it needs to much mem and to reassign while runtime needs to long to load. (1 sec for 50 Images)

Also I needed to RELASE and set to NIL, because otherwise it would even make my memory usage out of limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to do something like this:

```
if (someObject != nil)
{
    [someObject release];
    someObject = nil;
}
```

However, I don't think you should be releasing myimageview.image, assuming that myimageview is a `UIImageView`. The UIImageView is responsible for managing its image; you shouldn't be messing with its retain count.

Maybe what you really want to do is this:

```
myimageview.image = nil;
```

This will cause `myimageview` to release it *and* stop pointing to the now-invalid memory.

Comment: did not worked.. solved it now with:

 if ([myimageview.image retainCount] > 1) [myimageview.image release];

Comment: Using `retainCount` is a bad idea.  It should only be used for debugging, not for actual program logic, because it does not necessarily represent the actual number of retaining objects.  What you are doing may seem to work, but it's not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2):

You never, **ever**, release a property of another object. You release the entire `myimageview` object, or you just assign to it's properties. How those properties are memory manged is the private business of the `myimageview` object.

Comment: is right.  There should never be a situation where you release other object's properties for it.  I doubt that you have really "solved" it; you have just hacked around a bug.

Answer (score -2):

solved it with

if ([myimageview.image retainCount] > 1) [myimageview.image release];